# Visual Studio Code typescript auto import not working

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

As the title stated my VS Code doesn't auto import my modules, I'm trying to import `MatDialogModule` in the image below and it doesn't show me any Angular Material options

[image]

Comment: Try restarting VSCode

Comment: restart, uninstall, reinstall, i did all already

Comment: I have similar problem still with Angular 12 and using Angular Material. I have found this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37812#issuecomment-804190514 So it might be problem in Material library. It might be broken. Or maybe this is result of how they change preferred import style. Earlier you imported all from root index.ts but now from separate spesific path.

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue in Angular 13.

Answer (score 14):

For Angular 13, below solution worked for me:
Add this in tsconfig.json under compilerOptions.

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@angular/material"]
```

Comment: FYI the issue with Material modules is still there in Angular 15 and this solution works. I believe that's the best (only?) way to solve this based on the analysis pointed out by Janne Harju in OP's comments.

Comment: Issue persist in Angular 16 and this solution works

Comment: Issue persist in Angular 17 and this solution works (Is there a better solution?)

Answer (score 3):

VSCode is not able to auto import module from directories which have more than two path segments. However, this is true only for the first time you import a module inside a project.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution worked for me. Add the following section to tsconfig.json under compilerOptions:

```
"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "node_modules/@angular",
      "node_modules/@angular/material"]
```

Comment: this worked for me using Angular 16, I had no auto import completion for things like MatButtonModule adding the above now results in the imports being created for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking if you have done this first, `import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';`, as the type comes from `/dialog` directory.

It'd also be more helpful if you could attach your package.json file to your question, and show what you have installed so far. Did you use Angular CLI to install the Material modules?

You might find following links helpful:

- https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started
- https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-material-from-beginning/
- https://yogeshdotnet.com/angular-material-installation-setup-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 0):

As woodykiddy said, is `@angular/material` a dependency in your package.json? If not, add it and run `npm i` or `yarn` or the install command for your chosen package manager.